# Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun

Tags: c++, memory, virtual-machine, buffer, shared-memory

In my application I'm creating a buffer of some type that is provided through its usage:

```
read<uint64_t>(address);
```

---

```
template<typename T>
inline T read(uint64_t address)
{
    T buffer{ };
    readbuffer(address, &buffer, sizeof(T));
    return buffer;
}
```

---

I'm sending this buffer over a socket to a virtual machine which then finds the current process using `GetCurrentProcessId()` and writes the data I require back to the memory address of the buffer.

I then return that buffer which should now be the memory address. This issue I'm having is eventually when my code gets to a function which does a `return` statement it is triggering a stack-based buffer overrun and I can't figure out why.

More Info:

```
uint32_t readbuffer(uint64_t address, PVOID buffer, size_t size)
{
    if (address == 0)
        return false;
    printf("readbuffer: 0x%X  0x%X  0x%X\n", address, uintptr_t(buffer), size);
    return copy_memory(cached_connection, cached_dwPID, address, GetCurrentProcessId(), uintptr_t(buffer), size);
}
```

.

```
static uint32_t copy_memory(
    const SOCKET    connection,
    const uint32_t  src_process_id,
    const uintptr_t src_address,
    const uint32_t  dest_process_id,
    const uintptr_t dest_address,
    const size_t    size)
{
    Packet packet{ };

    packet.header.magic = packet_magic;
    packet.header.type = PacketType::packet_copy_memory;

    auto& data = packet.data.copy_memory;
    data.src_process_id = src_process_id;
    data.src_address = uint64_t(src_address);
    data.dest_process_id = dest_process_id;
    data.dest_address = uint64_t(dest_address);
    data.size = uint64_t(size);

    //printf("src 0x%X dst 0x%X size 0x%X\n", data.src_address, data.dest_address, data.size);

    uint64_t result = 0;
    if (send_packet(connection, packet, result))
        return uint32_t(result);

    return 0;
}
```

FROM THE virtual machine:

```
process->Read(completion_packet.data.copy_memory.src_address, &buffer, completion_packet.data.copy_memory.size);


destProcess->Write(completion_packet.data.copy_memory.dest_address, buffer);
```

Code that calls read/1 and crashes

```
FTransform GetBoneIndex(DWORD_PTR mesh, int index)
{
    DWORD_PTR bonearray = memio->read<DWORD_PTR>(mesh + 0x410);

    return memio->read<FTransform>(bonearray + (index * 0x30));
}
```

Read / Write method

```
template<typename T>
T Read(uint64_t address)
{
    T ret;
    VMemRead(&ctx->process, proc.dirBase, (uint64_t)&ret, address, sizeof(T));
    return ret;
}

template<typename T>
void Write(uint64_t address, const T& value)
{
    VMemWrite(&ctx->process, proc.dirBase, (uint64_t)&value, address, sizeof(T));
}
```

I'm now using these:

```
ssize_t WinProcess::Read(uint64_t address, void* buffer, size_t sz)
{
    return VMemRead(&ctx->process, proc.dirBase, (uint64_t)buffer, address, sz);
}

ssize_t WinProcess::Write(uint64_t address, void* buffer, size_t sz)
{
    return VMemWrite(&ctx->process, proc.dirBase, (uint64_t)buffer, address, sz);
}
```

Comment: What does `readbuffer` look like?

Comment: Could you show the code that calls `read`?

Comment: Let me update now with that info

Comment: @Botje Update code

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have example in post e.g. FTransform ComponentToWorld = read<FTransform>(mesh + 0x1C0);

Comment: Where is the code that calls `read`?

Comment: How does the Write method know how many bytes to copy? Is this `buffer` yet another container that knows its size?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I've added the code to the bottom of the post for read/1

Comment: @Botje if you check copy_memory function I send the information over the socket for how large the buffer is named `size_t size`

Comment: Again, how does the `Write` method know that? You just pass it two pointers!

Comment: @user952242 you should show us the `Write` method.

Comment: Thanks both I've added both read and write methods in

Comment: I guess its because the size thats being used is the size of my buffer which is incorrect?

Comment: I'm now writing using the correct size

`destProcess->Write(completion_packet.data.copy_memory.dest_address, buffer, completion_packet.data.copy_memory.size);`

which seems to be working but I'm not getting the correct address within process so will continue debugging

Comment: Thank's to both of you, if one of you wanna answer this I will give you a green tick @Botje this issue was the size being written was incorrect